# ¿Cómo restar cada valor de un array con cada valor de otro array?

Tags: php

Tengo estos dos array:

```
$matriz0 = array(2, 4, 8, 8, 10) 
$matriz1 = array(2, 7, 4, 7, 2)
```

Y quisiera saber como puedo formar un tercer array **matriz2** que contenga los resultados de restar cada valor del array **matriz0** con los cada valor del array **matriz1** es decir:

```
2-2  = 0
4-7  = -3
8-4  = 4
8-7  = 1
10-2 = 8
```

El tercer array quedaria:

```
matriz2 = array(0, -3, 4, 1, 8)
```

Es posible hacer esto que quiero, de serlo, como puedo lograrlo. Este es el codigo que intente:

```
$matriz0 = array(2, 4, 8, 8, 10);
$matriz1 = array(2, 7, 4, 7, 2); 
$matriz2=array();

foreach ( $matriz0 as $key0 => $valor0  ){
 foreach ( $matriz1 as $key1 => $valor1 ){
  $matriz2[] = $key0-$key1;
 }
}

echo var_dump($matriz2);
```

Peor cuando veo el var_dump no es la matriz que esperaba que me formara, como puedo lograr el resultado que quiero.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Podrias agregar que probaste hasta ahora.. y estas diciendo que queres restar los valores de matriz0 contra todos los valores de matriz1, pero en el ejemplo solo estas mostrando una resta posicional (que supongo que es lo que finalmente queres). Podrias aclararlo? edita la pregunta de ser necesario. Gracias.

Comment: exacto, lo que quiero es restar los valores de cada array haciendo coincidir las mismas posiciones

Comment: ok. y que intestaste hasta ahora?

Comment: trate de recorrer el primer array con un foreach y dentro de este otro foreach con el otro array, para despues restar valor por valor segun su posición, pero no me funciona, no se si es correcto esto

Comment: ese codigo es el que tenes que mostrar.. nadie va a escribir el codigo por vos, pero podemos corregirlo.. por favor mira los links que te describi en el primer comentario

Comment: Esta es al forma en que trate de hacerlo:

$matriz0 = array(2, 4, 8, 8, 10);
$matriz1 = array(2, 7, 4, 7, 2); 
$matriz2=array();

foreach ( $matriz0 as $key0 => $valor0  ){
 foreach ( $matriz1 as $key1 => $valor1 ){
  $matriz2[] = $key0-$key1;
 }
}

echo var_dump($matriz2);

Pero cuando ejecuto el var_dump, no es la matriz que esperaba

Comment: agrega esto a tu pregunta y lo vemos. no uses los comentarios para agregar el codigo que va en la pregunta

Comment: puedes editar tu pregunta dando click [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/82279/edit)

Comment: por favor una vez que tengas una solucion que te sirva, acepta la misma para que proximos usuarios sepan cual solucion te fue efectiva.

Comment: disculparme, pero las 3 me han servido,

Comment: debes señalar una sola como aceptada.. pon la que quieras para tu caso.. o la que entro primero.. pero puedes destacar como comentario que las tres te sirvieron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero debes comparar que los dos arrays tengan la misma dimensión, una vez que se comprueba eso solo debes hacer un for que recorra n-veces(la dimension de los arrays) y hacer la suma y asignarlo al nuevo arreglo:

```
$matriz0 = array(2, 4, 8, 8, 10);
$matriz1 = array(2, 7, 4, 7, 2); 
$matriz2 = array();
if ( count($matriz0) == count($matriz1) )
    for ($i=0; $i < count($matriz0); $i++)
        array_push($matriz2, ($matriz0[$i] - $matriz1[$i]) );
var_dump($matriz2);
```

Comment: Gracias colega es lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1):

un ejemplo con **[`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php)** te servira para otras cosas

```
 $a = array(2, 4, 8, 8, 10);
 $b = array(2, 7, 4, 7, 2); 
 $c = array_map(function ($x, $y) { return $y-$x; } , $a, $b);

 print_r($c);
```

si uno de los dos array es mayor simplemente los anexa no realiza la operacion arimetica

```
$a = array(2, 4, 8, 8, 10);
$b = array(2, 7, 4, 7, 2,9); 
$c = array_map(function ($x, $y) { return $y-$x; } , $a, $b);

print_r($c);
```

el resultado para el ultmio caso es el siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => -4
    [3] => -1
    [4] => -8
    [5] => 9
)
```

observe que se agrego el numero `9` sin realizar la operacion; no esta en **`negativo`**

Comment: gracias por el aporte

Comment: en caso de vectores de diferentes longitudes que hace array_map?

Comment: lo anexa aqui el ejemplo pero no hace la operacion http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b7ee78137d31b978444bdee8da0536c96d7a2626

Comment: Buena respuesta. Ese último comentario creo que es importante que esté en la respuesta. Muchos de los que la lean se van a preguntar exactamente eso: qué pasa cuando `count($a) < count($b)`, y qué pasa cuando `count($a) > count($b)`

Comment: listo agrege el comentario

Answer (score 0):

Si lo usas bastante, lo mejor es definir una funcion

```
<?php 
    function subArray($arrA, $arrB)
    {
        $result = [];
        $elem = count($arrA);

        if ($elem == count($arrB)) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $elem; $i++) {
                $result[$i] = $arrA[$i] - $arrB[$i];
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    $matriz0 = array(2, 4, 8, 8, 10);
    $matriz1 = array(2, 7, 4, 7, 2);
    $result = subArray($matriz0, $matriz1);
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: gracias, me viene bien esta otra forma de lograrlo.